# How can i install python on OSX?

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to computer programming!
I want to learn python and write my program and run it on my mac OS X machine.
How can i setup python programming tools on OS X and how can i use that ?
I before this never use any other programming language.

Comment: open a terminal and type 'python'.  You'll see that it's already included in OSX.  Type exit() to get out of the command line interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python is installed on OSX by default
and you just need to open terminal and write ‘python’ command, then you can start your python coding